# How to record and store Twilio SMS in MySQL with no additional action?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

What I am trying to accomplish is quite simple. I want to store all received SMS messages from a Twilio number in a database. Upon checking Twilio's documentation, their TwiML word  should be able to do this, but no attribute relates to this:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When your Twilio number gets sent an SMS, your application receives a webhook at the URL you supply in the settings for the number. For each messages, the webhook sends a number of parameters telling you about the message. The documentation for that can be found here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request.

You might want to take a look at our [PHP Quickstart tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey) which will give you a good idea of how to get the details from the request. You will then just have to pick which attributes you want to store in your database.

Let me know if this helps.